# MATLAB nlinfit with multiple unknowns

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve using **`nlinfit`**, however, I have 3 unknowns.

The equation that I am trying to fit is the laminar velocity profile in a tube.

**`u = umax( 1 - ( r / R ) ^ 2 )`**, where `u` is the velocity, `umax` is the centerline velocity, `r` is the distance from the centerline and `R` is the radius of the tube.

The problem is that `umax`, `r` and `R` are unknowns.

http://www.mne.psu.edu/cimbala/learning/fluid/CV_Momentum/pipe_eg.gif
[image]

From the image above, the centerline is the axis. I have included code for 1 set of data:

```
clc
clear all

XMean = [0.13518 
0.1599
0.17035
0.18053
0.18849
0.19577
0.19373
0.18781
0.17245
0.15728
0.13404
0.10981];

r = [-5.5000
   -4.5000
   -3.5000
   -2.5000
   -1.5000
   -0.5000
    0.5000
    1.5000
    2.5000
    3.5000
    4.5000
    5.5000];

plot( XMean, r )
```

I am not sure how to format the equation handle:

```
Eqn = @(u,y) u(1).*( 1 - ( ( u(2) - y ) / u(3) ).^2 );

[ beta, R, J, CovB, MSE ] = nlinfit( YMean, r, Eqn, Alpha );
```

I would appreciate any help trying to fit this data. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

In order to compute the rmse it is neccessary to have a maximum of 1 y value per x value, mathematically speaking a "function". You can plot later again the way your sketch shows it. But for the computation: rotate by 90 degree.

For the optimization, you need an initiall guess (your `Alpha`), which is not defined. However, with some minor changes in the code below, one can get the optimal parameters. Also it might be better readable. The plot is shown below.

```
plot(r, XMean ,'ko', 'markerfacecolor', 'black') % // need a "function" (max 1y value for 1x-value)
Eqn = @(par, x) par(1).*( 1 - ( (par(2) - x) / par(3) ).^2 );
par0 = [1, 1, 1]; % // an initial guess as start for optimization
par_fit = nlinfit(r, XMean, Eqn, par0 ); % // optimize
hold on
r_fit = linspace(min(r), max(r)); % // more points for smoother curve
plot(r_fit, Eqn(par_fit, r_fit), 'r')
```

[image]
The optimal parameters i get returned are

```
par_fit =

    0.1940   -0.4826    9.0916
```

You might want to rotate the plot again to get it into the right orientation, as in your sketch.

## Additional Info: polyfit() instead of nlinfit

Since one can compute this flow profile analytically, one knows in advance that is is a parabola. You can also use `polyfit` to fit a parabola.

```
par_poly_fit = polyfit(r, XMean, 2)

% // it yields the values:
par_poly_fit =

-0.0023   -0.0023    0.1934
```

Plotting that paraobla gives a line pretty much identical to the line, which we got with the optimizer, but it is just more stable since it does not depend on an initial value.

```
 plot(r_fit, polyval(par_poly_fit, r_fit),'g--'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do I need to rotate the graph in order to fit the curve?

Comment: Because you are defining a fit function ``Eqn``. That fit function will return 1 value for 1 input value + parameters. Consider my plot, for instance for the value -4 the fit function returns something like 0.16. But what if the plot was rotated? Which value on the x-axis should the fit function return if i was to put in 0.16 and the parameters? Should it return -4 or + 4?